# When deploying ASP.NET app via TeamCity/Octopus, Application Insights stops working

Tags: teamcity, azure-application-insights, octopus-deploy

I have an asp.net webapi project deployed in Azure which has Application Insights active (and works very nicely). AI was activated in the Azure portal i.e. no change required in the project (very nice).

However, I have now added the Application Insights nugets to my project so i can experiment with adding my own custom dependencies. But when I deploy through git commit (which triggers TeamCity and Octopus), Application Insights stops working. This is evident in that Live Metrics will not start.

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the ApplicationInsights.config file was not being deployed by octupus. Solution was to update my nuspec file to include this file as part of the nuget package construction.

I noticed this when comparing the files deployed by the IDE Publish against what Octopus deploys.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some conflict between extension and application. Can you uninstall the Application Insights extension from Azure portal and try again?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that with no success. One interesting thing I found last thing yesterday is that when I deploy directly to the server using Publish within Visual Studio it works. I need to investigate this further today...

Comment: Ok. How do you set ikey? Need to ensure that i key is correctly set in the WebApp.